# PHPExcel error while creating object, Unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, syntax-error, phpexcel

I was working with PHPExcel to generate a list for my PHP application.

```
//Nothing significant before if

if($type == "StudentList")
{
PHPExcel $ex  = new PHPExcel();
$ex->getProperties()->setTitle("Student List.xlsx");
//rest of the code follows
```

At the line `PHPExcel $ex = new PHPExcel();` I get an error saying `unexpected T_VARIABLE`. I have included the path to the PHPExcel.php file and included the file as well. I don't seem to understand what could the error possibly be? Any help is much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to take out the word `PHPExcel` in `PHPExcel $ex = new PHPExcel();` try `$ex = new PHPExcel();`

Comment: Hey fred! Howz you mate.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Hey Shankar, doing well thanks, hope you're the same too. Am working hard on learning MySQLi/PDO, loving every moment and building working stuff too :)

Comment: Yeah same here lol. Working on building an android app with PHP PDO as a webservice. ^_^

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I'm gonna have to learn to build those (some day) lol won't have a choice. Will Tweet you brother, just haven't been on it lately.

Comment: Please don't use SO comments for private chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This. It works

```
  if($type == "StudentList") {
  //PHPExcel
  $ex = new PHPExcel();
  $ex->getProperties()->setTitle("Student List.xlsx");
  }
```